# how to vertically align the 2 different font sizes inside a single <p>

Tags: html, css

As the title says, how should I vertically align this:-

Need: - - | - | - -

Currently the vertical alignment is by default at baseline.

Currently: _ _ | _ | _ _

HTML:

```
<div class="moduleResult">
    <p>You have
        <span class="moduleCard">88</span>
        out of
        <span class="moduleCard">88</span>
    correct</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.moduleResult{
    width:100%;
    }

p{
    font-family:'Arial';
    font-size:20px !important;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    }

.moduleCard{
    font-size:60px !important;
    line-height:60px;
    padding:0 4px;
    }
```

and the text has to be aligned centred inside a < div class"moduleResult" >

here's the **[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/kfVGf/1/)**

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;` is the key!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/kfVGf/2/

```
.moduleCard{
    font-size:60px !important;
    padding:0 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

---

Result:

[image]

---

Note: [unless you have a valid reason](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/) for it, avoid to use `!important`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The `!important` was required :) Not here, but at the place where I'm using it.